# ASP.Net update panels Large Memory usage in chrome

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, google-chrome, memory-leaks

ok, I have looked at [Why do Asp.net timers/updatepanels leak memory in Chrome and can it be fixed/worked around?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053855/why-do-asp-net-timers-updatepanels-leak-memory-in-chrome-and-can-it-be-fixed-wor) and [Unbind Events in ASP UpdatePanel BEFORE Ajax Request to prevent Memory Leak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15913738/unbind-events-in-asp-updatepanel-before-ajax-request-to-prevent-memory-leak).

I have inherited an ASP.NET intranet site that updates with live data using update panels.  Within 10 minutes of opening this site in Chrome, the Chrome instance's Memory usage on the client (not the server) will be sitting at ~1.5 GB.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server"></asp:Timer>    
         ABG Stock Price <asp:LinkButton ID="CAR_News" runat="server"                 
            href="http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=CAR" ToolTip="Click for news about CAR"
            target="blank">(CAR)</asp:LinkButton>: <asp:Label ID="lbl_StockPrice" runat="server"></asp:Label>   
        <asp:Label ID="lbl_StockChange" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        <asp:Label ID="lbl_StockChangePct" runat="server"></asp:Label><br />
        <asp:Label ID="lbl_StockLastUpdated" runat="server" Font-Size="Small"></asp:Label>
        <br /><br />            
        <div id="div_stock_Compare" runat="server" style="font-size:smaller;"><b>Competitor Stock Prices</b><br />
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Hertz <asp:LinkButton ID="lb_HTZ_News" runat="server"
            href="http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=HTZ" ToolTip="Click for news about HTZ"
            target="_blank">(HTZ)</asp:LinkButton>: <asp:Label ID="lbl_StockPrice_Hertz" runat="server"></asp:Label>   
            <asp:Label ID="lbl_StockChange_Hertz" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            <asp:Label ID="lbl_StockChangePct_Hertz" runat="server"></asp:Label><br />                

            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;U-Haul <asp:LinkButton ID="lb_UHAL_News" runat="server"
            href="http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=UHAL" ToolTip="Click for news about UHAL"
            target="_blank">(UHAL)</asp:LinkButton>: <asp:Label ID="lbl_StockPrice_uhal" runat="server"></asp:Label>   
            <asp:Label ID="lbl_StockChange_uhal" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            <asp:Label ID="lbl_StockChangePct_uhal" runat="server"></asp:Label><br />                
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Ryder <asp:LinkButton ID="lb_R_News" runat="server"
            href="http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=R" ToolTip="Click for news about R"
            target="_blank">(R)</asp:LinkButton>: <asp:Label ID="lbl_StockPrice_ryd" runat="server"></asp:Label>   
            <asp:Label ID="lbl_StockChange_ryd" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            <asp:Label ID="lbl_StockChangePct_ryd" runat="server"></asp:Label><br />
        </div>                            
    </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>   

    <br />
    <!-- reports section --> 
        <table width="100%" id="report_table_1">
        <tr>
            <td style="width:50%; text-align:left;">
                <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="********" runat="server" 
                    DocumentMapCollapsed="True" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" 
                    ProcessingMode="Remote" ShowCredentialPrompts="False" 
                    ShowDocumentMapButton="False" ShowFindControls="False" 
                    ShowPageNavigationControls="False" ShowParameterPrompts="False" 
                    ShowPromptAreaButton="False" Width="100%" Height="150px"
                    SizeToReportContent="True" ShowPrintButton="False" 
                    ShowExportControls="False" ShowRefreshButton="False" ShowToolBar="False" 
                    ZoomMode="FullPage" AsyncRendering="false">
                    <ServerReport ReportPath="******" 
                    ReportServerUrl="***********" />
                    </rsweb:ReportViewer>
            </td>
            <td style="width:50%; text-align:left;">
                <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="***********" runat="server" 
                    DocumentMapCollapsed="True" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" 
                    ProcessingMode="Remote" ShowCredentialPrompts="False" 
                    ShowDocumentMapButton="False" ShowFindControls="False" 
                    ShowPageNavigationControls="False" ShowParameterPrompts="False" 
                    ShowPromptAreaButton="False" Width="100%"
                    SizeToReportContent="True" ShowPrintButton="False" 
                    ShowExportControls="False" ShowRefreshButton="False" ShowToolBar="False" 
                    ZoomMode="FullPage" AsyncRendering="false">
                    <ServerReport ReportPath="***********" 
                    ReportServerUrl="*********" />
                    </rsweb:ReportViewer>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        <table width="100%" id="report_table_2">
        <tr>
            <td style="width:50%; text-align:left;"> 
                <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="*******" runat="server"
                        DocumentMapCollapsed="True" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt"
                        Height="430px" Width="100%"
                        ProcessingMode="Remote" ShowCredentialPrompts="False" 
                        ShowDocumentMapButton="False" ShowFindControls="False" 
                        ShowPageNavigationControls="False" ShowParameterPrompts="False" 
                        ShowPromptAreaButton="False" 
                        SizeToReportContent="True" ShowPrintButton="False" 
                        ShowExportControls="False" ShowRefreshButton="False" 
                        ShowToolBar="False" EnableTheming="False" AsyncRendering="false">
                        <ServerReport ReportPath="********" 
                        ReportServerUrl="********" />
                        </rsweb:ReportViewer></td>               
            <td style="width:50%; text-align:left;" valign="top" visible="false">
                <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="****" runat="server" Visible="false"
                        DocumentMapCollapsed="True" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt"
                        Height="430px" Width="100%"
                        ProcessingMode="Remote" ShowCredentialPrompts="False" 
                        ShowDocumentMapButton="False" ShowFindControls="False" 
                        ShowPageNavigationControls="False" ShowParameterPrompts="False" 
                        ShowPromptAreaButton="False" 
                        SizeToReportContent="True" ShowPrintButton="False" 
                        ShowExportControls="False" ShowRefreshButton="False" AsyncRendering="false" 
                        ShowToolBar="False">
                        <ServerReport ReportPath="******" 
                        ReportServerUrl="********" />
                        </rsweb:ReportViewer></td>                            
        </tr>
        </table>
```

But as of yet, I have not found a good fix/workaround for this.... I will admit that I am kind of an amateur when it comes to ASP.